# Oracle SQL, Combine rows based off of corresponding attributes from another select

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to combine the "COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID)" column based on if the "LOCATION_ID" are the same as the corresponding "DEPARTMENT_ID" from another select statement. I have this select statement that gives me how many times "DEPARTMENT_ID" comes up.

```
select DEPARTMENT_ID, COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID)
------------- --------------------
          100                    6
           30                    6
                                 0
           90                    3
           20                    2
           70                    1
          110                    2
           50                   45
           80                   34
           40                    1
           60                    5

DEPARTMENT_ID COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID)
------------- --------------------
           10                    1

12 rows selected.
```

And I have this other select that tells me what "DEPARTMENT_ID" corresponding "LOCATION_ID" is but I am not sure how to combine the "COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID)" based on if the "LOCATION_ID" are the same.

```
select DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION_ID from DEPARTMENTS;
```

Output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- -----------
           10        1700
           20        1800
           30        1700
           40        2400
           50        1500
           60        1400
           70        2700
           80        2500
           90        1700
          100        1700
          110        1700

DEPARTMENT_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- -----------
          120        1700
          130        1700
          140        1700
          150        1700
          160        1700
          170        1700
          180        1700
          190        1700
          200        1700
          210        1700
          220        1700

DEPARTMENT_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- -----------
          230        1700
          240        1700
          250        1700
          260        1700
          270        1700

27 rows selected.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to simply count the number of departments based on its location then the below query would be suffice.

```
select LOCATION_ID, count(DEPARTMENT_ID) from DEPARTMENTS group by LOCATION_ID
```

If you need count of employees based on the location the you need to use inner join and group by location id.

```
 select t2.LOCATION_ID, COUNT(t1.DEPARTMENT_ID) 
FROM EMPLOYEES t1 INNER JOIN (select DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION_ID from  DEPARTMENTS) t2 
 on t1.DEPARTMENT_ID = t2.DEPARTMENT_ID  GROUP BY t2.LOCATION_ID ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated code:

You can use Inner Join, the INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables. You can use following query.

```
 select t1.DEPARTMENT_ID, COUNT(t1.DEPARTMENT_ID) ,t2.LOCATION_ID FROM EMPLOYEES t1 INNER JOIN (select DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION_ID from  DEPARTMENTS) t2 
    on t1.DEPARTMENT_ID = t2.DEPARTMENT_ID  GROUP BY t1.DEPARTMENT_ID,t2.LOCATION_ID ;
```

Comment: I get this error: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select t1.DEPARTMENT_ID,t1.countDept,t2.LOCATION_ID from 
(select DEPARTMENT_ID, COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) as countDept FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID) as t1 
INNER JOIN (select DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION_ID from  DEPARTMENTS) as t2 
on t1.DEPARTMENT_ID=t2.DEPARTMENT_ID 
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 97
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Gives this error: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select t1.DEPARTMENT_ID, COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) ,t2.LOCATION_ID FROM EMPLOYEES t1 INNER JOIN (select DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION_ID from  DEPARTMENTS) t2 
    on t1.DEPARTMENT_ID = t2.DEPARTMENT_ID  GROUP BY t1.DEPARTMENT_ID,t2.LOCATION_ID 
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 32
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Use **COUNT( t1.DEPARTMENT_ID)** instead of COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID). I have updated code in the answer as well

Comment: DEPARTMENT_ID         S1 LOCATION_ID
------------- ---------- -----------
           30          6        1700
           20          2        1800
           40          1        2400
           90          3        1700
          110          2        1700
           70          1        2700
           80         34        2500
           60          5        1400
           10          1        1700
           50         45        1500
          100          6        1700

Comment: It is close, I just need to combine s1 based on if location_id is the same.